# How to convert Number 23.0 to Number 23.00?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In my highcharts case, I want to make custom axis labels,but in tickPositioners,I use the toFixed to handle the number to be a fload number,the number became a string.

So,how can I make the following result to be 23.20?

```
var a = 23.2;
var b = a.toFixed(2); //23.20
//typof b = string
var c = +b; // 23.2
```

Comment: Number cannot be `23.20`, just string.

Comment: (23.2 * 100) / 100. ?

Comment: Instead of using `tickPositioner`, use `labels.formatter` ;) TickPositioner should return array of numbers, while formatter is responsible for displayed numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If `b` is number type it cannot be `23.20`, it can be only `23.2`. If your goal is performing mathematical operations you don't need to do this kind of conversion (which is not even possible because mathematically `23.20` becomes `23.2` automatically). Only reason why you have to do this kind of conversion is for display or for printing. For example if the value `23.2` is currency value you may want to print `23.20` for displaying on the screen. Such a problem has been already addressed by java sprintf: https://github.com/alexei/sprintf.js.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was highcharts source code for handling numbers, I just seperate integer numbers from decimal numbers to resolve this problem.'23.20' can only be string.